# IntelliJ Idea: Column of entity class cannot be resolved

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I have setup a multi-module java project in intellij idea (version 13.1.4), seperating the different application layers in different modules. It uses hibernate on top of jpa for the persistence layer. Amongst others there is a core module that contains the configuration of the persistence unit. I have already set up the required facades (jpa, hibernate) as well as the database connection and the persistence mapping to the datasource. IntelliJ recognizes database queries for an instance quite well. Even in modules that have no persistence mapping of their own.

Now for the problem. I have another module that holds all the entities used for the object-relational-mapping. For an instance:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "column_name")
    private Long entityId;
}
```

IntelliJ shows a validation error stating that it cannot resolve the database column even though it definitely exists. I can as well browse it in the database view. This goes for the other fields as well.

Im sure I must have setup something wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try synchronizing the data source in the database view of IntelliJ so the information about columns get updated? Even if you can browse it, its not necessarily synched with the rest of the project.

Comment: Do you have an explicit dependency between the entity's module and the module containing the persistence unit configuration?

Comment: Also, which version of intellij?

Comment: @MrPixelDream: Yes I already tried synchronizing the data-source to no avail though.

Comment: @EngineerDolly: The IntelliJ version is 13.1.4. The dependency is in fact the other way around. The module containing the persitence unit configuration depends on the entity's module.

Comment: Is the case matching? I had a problem using "column_name", where the name really was "COLUMN_NAME".

Comment: @DarekKay: I already tried that. Also with no success. Funny thing is, there are some entity classes in the module that are recognized. Maybe the problem is located somewhere in the class itself. I'll look into that when im back at work.